# Old pen-pal short story

Tags: story-identification, aliens, short-stories

I remember a short story about someone with an alien pen-pal; over the years he goes through ups and downs and shares with his pen-pal who is supportive always. Eventually he gets to see a picture of her, and learns that she is a very icky stinky non-human alien. He writes to her and tells her he's seen her picture, and thinks she is 'most beautiful'.

I'd like to get this for my daughter - anyone know what it might be? I read it in a short story collection, possibly from a sci-fi magazine. It's maybe 1950's or 1960's vintage?

Answer (score 9):

That's ["P.S"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?90496) by Eric Frank Russell. The link goes to ISFDB's bibliography of where it has been published.

A summary, and a link to a legal copy of the contents of the magazine it was published in are available [here](http://variety-sf.blogspot.com/2010/10/eric-frank-russell-postscript-aka-ps.html).

> Dr Malcolm Harrison, now 77, had made a pen-pal 65 years ago with Gaily (aka Vandashanda), a "girl" who's a native of the far away world Reba. They've been good friends ever since, & still exchange letters.
>
> One fine day, Doc accidentally stumbles into Jim Corlett, a much younger acquaintance in Space Service who'd recently returned from 17 years in space. Among the gossip exchanged is Jim's 2 days stop at Reba, & his repulsive reaction to its intelligent smelly native fungi! He even has brought back a picture of 6 natives - among them one Vandashanda!
>
> How should the Doc be affected by the revelation that his long time friend "Gaily" is not a woman but smelly fungus?